# STDOUT and STDERR log rotation TOMCAT in windows

Tags: logging, solr, stdout, tomcat8, log-rotation

I’m new to solr and not very good with java.

we are using solr as our search solution and tomcat is hosted as a service in windows and solr is runs in tomcat.

We are trying to implement log rotation for tomcat. We tried using `log4j.properties` in and `logging.properties`. But for sine reason the stdout and stderr are still piling up and are consuming a lot of space.

We are using `log4j.properties` to rotate solr logs.

Grateful if we could get some help for rotating stdout and stderr logs.

We have tried 3 different methods and none of them worked as expected.

1. Added stdout to log4j.properties

   > solr.log=logs/
   >   log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
   >
   > log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   >
   > log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   >   log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x \u2013 %m%n
   >
   > ## size rotation with log cleanup.
   >
   > log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
   >   log4j.appender.stdout.MaxFileSize=4MB
   >   log4j.appender.stdout.MaxBackupIndex=9
   >
   > ## - File to log to and log format
   >
   > log4j.appender.stdout.File=${solr.log}/solr.log
   >   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   >   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}; %C; %m\n
2. Added file size limit to logging.properties in tomcat.

   > java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 2000000 
   >   java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 5
3. Update the Java properties in Monitor Tomcat applications.

added the below to java option under java tab in tomcat

> -Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=25000000

All theese attempts failed and we had to restart the tomcat to rotate the file which is not desirable in production.

Tomcat: 8.0.20
Solr: 4.10.3
OS: Windows